# adOpenKeyset issue in excel vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to extract the data with ADODB connection through VBA but when i run throgh this code `recset.Open strSQL, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`
my excel is automatically getting closed.
Is there anything which i am missing?

```
Sub Show_data()


    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset

'Check for the connectivity or connected to the xx network
    On Error GoTo errHandler

errHandler:
    If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
        MsgBox "Please check for the xx connectivity ", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If


    ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;User ID=myuser;password= mypass;Data Source=mys"

    con.Open ConnectionString

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'

        strSQL = "SELECT B.USER_NAME AS CREATED_BY, A.CREATION_DATE, C.USER_NAME, A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, A.PFIZER_ITEMCODE, A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE AS ORACLE_ITEM_CODE, " & _
        "A.ITEM_DESCRIPTION, A.BATCH_NUMBER, A.MFR_CODE, A.MFR_DESC AS MFR_DESCRIPTION, TO_CHAR(A.MFR_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')As MFR_DATE, TO_CHAR(A.EXPIRY_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')As EXPIRY_DATE, " & _
        "TO_CHAR(A.EFFECTIVE_FROM,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_FROM, " & _
        "A.EFFECTIVE_TO, A.EXCISE AS EXCISE_AMOUNT, A.EXCISE_RATE, A.P2S, A.P2R, A.MRP, A.STATE_CODE, A.STATE, " & _
        "(CASE SUBSTR(A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE,6,2) WHEN ('PI') THEN 'OIP' WHEN ('PF') THEN 'OPF' ELSE 'OWL' END )AS LEGAL_ENTITY " & _
        "FROM xxdhl_pf_batch_pricing A JOIN fnd_user B ON A.CREATED_BY = B.USER_ID " & _
        "JOIN fnd_user C ON A.LAST_UPDATED_BY = C.USER_ID WHERE "


        If (ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text) <> "" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " (CASE SUBSTR(A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE,6,2) WHEN ('PI') THEN 'OIP' WHEN ('PF') THEN 'OPF' ELSE 'OWL' END )='" & ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text & "'"
        End If

        If (ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text) <> "" Then
            If (ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text) <> "" Then
                strSQL = strSQL & " AND A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE='" & ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text & "'"
            Else
                strSQL = strSQL & " A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE='" & ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text & "'"
            End If
        End If

        If (ActiveSheet.txtBatch.Text) <> "" Then
            If (ActiveSheet.cmbLE.Text) <> "" Or (ActiveSheet.cmbProduct.Text) <> "" Then
                strSQL = strSQL & " AND A.BATCH_NUMBER='" & ActiveSheet.txtBatch.Text & "'"
            Else
                strSQL = strSQL & " A.BATCH_NUMBER='" & ActiveSheet.txtBatch.Text & "'"
            End If
        End If




    'Open Recordset

    Set recset.ActiveConnection = con
    recset.Open strSQL, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    'Copy the data
    If recset.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset recset
    Else
    MsgBox "No Data Available", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
    End If




recset.Close
con.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: The SO rules indicate you should provide a minimal code sample to reproduce the problem, but I think maybe you've gone to minimalistic. It would be helpful to see the definition of `con` and `strSQL`. It would also be good to know what you're connecting to.

Comment: hi @FreeMan.....i had editted my code...regret for not to provide in detail..pls check and see is there anything m missing...

Comment: First thing I would do is move your `errHandler:` to the end of the `Sub()`. As it stands, if you get any error that is _not_ -2147467259, execution will resume after that `end if`, and you'll be in some weird, unknown state...  Make sure you put `Exit Sub` just before the `errHandler:` label, or your code will continue execution into that block of code. Have you confirmed that you're not getting some other error that your error handler isn't handling?

Comment: @FreeMan...ys i checked by removing the err handler  bt the same issue is coming...excel is getting automatically close..

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with your connection's cursor location, by default it is adUseServer. When using keyset, you will probably want to use adUseClient. I know from using ms access that this is especially the case when attempting to bind the recordset to a form. Try opening the connection with adUseClient, hopefully it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Jamie....i checked as above but not working...my excel is automatically getting closed.